# Finding $p \in \mathbb{R}[t]$ such that $\left| \int_0^1 p^2(t)dt\right| > c\left( \int_0^1 |p(t)|dt\right)^2$ holds

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

I am looking for a polynomial $p \in \mathbb{R}[t]$, such that $$\left| \int_0^1 p^2(t)dt\right| > c\left( \int_0^1 |p(t)|dt\right)^2$$ holds for any $c > 0$. I tried some particular cases like $p = 1 + 2t$ or $p = ct$, but somehow I do not see the way to approach this. I think there is some key-observation one has to make or bare luck. Has anyone a slight hint for me, in which direction I should look?

**Edit.** Since $\int_0^1 |p(t)|dt$ is a norm on $\mathbb{R}[t]$, we can assume that $p \neq 0$. So we are looking for a polynomial, such that the LHS has at least degree $1$ in the variable $c$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shifted Legendre polynomials $\frac{P_n(2x-1)}{\sqrt{2n+1}}$ provide an orthonormal base of $L^2(0,1)$ with respect to the standard inner product. Assuming
$$ |p(x)| = \sum_{n\geq 0} a_n \frac{P_n(2x-1)}{\sqrt{2n+1}}$$
we have
$$ \int_{0}^{1}p(t)^2\,dt = \sum_{n\geq 0}a_n^2,\qquad \left(\int_{0}^{1}|p(t)|\,dt\right)^2 =a_0^2$$
hence the inequality $\int_{0}^{1}p(t)^2\,dt>c\left(\int_{0}^{1}|p(t)|\,dt\right)^2$ holds for every $c>0$ iff $a_0=0$ and some $a_k$ differs from zero. If $a_0=0$ then $|p(t)|$ has mean zero. But $|p(t)|$ is a continuous and non-negative function, so there are no solutions.